# MSIE not recognizing updates to selected items before .mouseup() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've got a setup with a couple `<select>` lists that allows you to perform various functions on the `<options>`s depending on which are selected. Originally I had a .change() event handler in place on the `<select>`s that would first find the selected elements in the list and update the states of my control buttons accordingly. (Certain features should be unavailable for certain items in the list).

However, strange behavior for .change() in MSIE<=8 led me to listen for arrow key presses and mouse clicks instead. I thought I was almost there, but it seems all versions of MSIE through v9 at least treat mouseup() and click() events differently than all the other browsers.

I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mjbmZ/4/

with src reproduced below:

html:

```
<select id='select' size='10' multiple='multiple'>
    <option value='asdf'>Opt 1</option>
    <option value='asdf2'>Opt 2</option>
    <option value='asdf3'>Opt 3</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
var selectList = $("#select");

var getCurrent = function (e) {
    currentSelections = selectList.find(':selected');
    var vals = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < currentSelections.length; x += 1) {
        vals.push($(currentSelections[x]).html());
    }
    console.log(e, vals.join(', '));
}

selectList.click( function () {
    getCurrent('click: ');
});
selectList.mouseup( function () {
    getCurrent('mouseup: ');
});
```

The code above will log the text for the selected options to the console when you click on any with your mouse... or it's supposed to.

In MSIE .mouseup() reports what was selected *before* the last click. All other major browsers get it right. So why not just use .click() for all of them instead?

Well, in all browsers EXCEPT MSIE, the .click() event doesn't fire at all if you hold the mouse down while selecting multiple options. Try it: put your mouse over Opt1, click, drag down so another option is highlighted with it, and then release. No .click() fired!

Anyway, I hope that made sense. I'd really like to normalize the behavior between the browsers but right now I seem forced to choose between:

1) using .change(), which isn't registering options selected via the keyboard in MSIE<9

or

2) using .keyup() events + .click() or .mouseup(), neither of which work consistently between browsers

Anyone have any ideas?

**[EDIT]**

I have dropped all the `.keyup()`, `.mouseup()`, and `.click()` events. The behavior is simply too inconsistent between the browsers. I have reverted to `.change()`, with a caveat:

I do a feature detection for `.addEvent` and attach a listener for `'onchange'` in that case. This resolves all the spotty issues I had with jQuery's `.change()` not firing in older versions of MSIE in when you:

1) made selections via the keyboard

2) did a multiple select with a click-drag

There is an updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mjbmZ/11/ for anyone who is interested. The updated code is implemented like this:

```
var selectList = $("#select");

var getCurrent = function (e) {
    currentSelections = selectList.find(':selected');
    var vals = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < currentSelections.length; x += 1) {
        vals.push($(currentSelections[x]).html());
    }
    console.log(e, vals.join(', '));
}


selectList.click( function () {
    getCurrent('click: ');
});
selectList.mouseup( function () {
    getCurrent('mouesup: ');
});
selectList.change( function () {
    getCurrent('change: ');
});
if (selectList[0].attachEvent) {
    selectList[0].attachEvent('onchange', function () {
        getCurrent('onchange: ');
    });
}
```

If you move through the selections with the keyboard in MSIE<9, you can see that only the 'onchange' event is firing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the change() and it's working in IE/Mozilla/Chrome

```
var selectList = $("#select");

var getCurrent = function(e) {
    currentSelections = $("#select :selected");
 vals = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < currentSelections.length; x += 1) {
        vals.push($(currentSelections[x]).html());
    }
    console.log(e, vals.join(', '));
}


selectList.change(function() {
    getCurrent('click: ');
});
```

Here's the link to the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/mjbmZ/5/

Comment: Ah.. Should have read carefully just saw it was only for <IE9

Comment: It only works for the simple case of clicking one element at a time in IE < v9. If you use v7/8 and make your selection with modifier key + arrow, OR do a one click drag select, it won't fire. That's actually why I turned to .mouseup(), .click(), and .keyup() in the first place, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you required to be on jQuery 1.6.4?  It seems to be working with the more recent packages

Comment: We are stuck with an old version of jQuery for now, yeah. In any event, I'm still seeing odd behavior even with the newer versions. I did find a solution though, which is to use the old elem.addEvent('onChange', callback). For some reason it doesn't show any of the odd behavior of jQuery's .change().